# <!DOCTYPE html> changes input textbox size (height and width)

Tags: css, html

My html page looked as I wanted, and suddently my input text-s became a bit larger than I wanted, I was trying to fix it and found out that `<!DOCTYPE html>` I placed  does this:

**with <!DOCTYPE html>**

[image]

**this is how it looked before putting <!DOCTYPE html>**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<select style="font-size:20px;padding-left:20px;border-radius:20px; height:40px;width:80%;max-width:500px;" onchange="change(this)" id="pitanja">
  <option value="1">Prvo pitanje?</option>
  <option value="2">Drugo pitanje?</option>
  <option value="3">Treće pitanje?</option>
  <option value="4">Četvrto pitanje?</option>
  <option value="5">Peto pitanje?</option>
  <option value="6">Šesto pitanje?</option>
  <option value="7">Sedmo pitanje?</option>
  <option value="8">Osmo pitanje?</option>
  <option value="9">Deveto pitanje?</option>
  <option value="10">Deseto pitanje?</option>
</select>

<p><input type="text" style="font-size:20px;padding-left:20px;border:solid 1px black;height:40px;width:80%;max-width:500px;border-radius:20px;" id="pitanje_text" onchange="change2(this)"/></p>
```

why does `<!DOCTYPE html>` cause this and should I remove it or there is a better solution? thanks!

Comment: try to add meyer web reset css to your page and then see if it still occurs

Comment: from what I see, the photos are exactly the same, except for the fact that they are cropped differently.

Comment: @SujitAgarwal it's still the same, it just removed space between option and textbox

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu - if you observe, the textbox below the select box is slightly wider

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu size of textbox changed, you can see that with doctype it is a bit larger in height and width, it was supposed to be the same size as option menu

Comment: doctype is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in. i don't think it will have any impact on font rendering

Comment: @DeepakVerma I'm sorry I was not precise enough, it changed textbox size not the text font size

Comment: Are you writing the css from scratch

Comment: Add the doctype to your HTML and change your CSS as necessary. See [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) for why they're different.

Comment: @joshmoto yes but even without it it's the same

Comment: tried what u said but same result for me check this without doctype https://codepen.io/ecazorla/pen/WKdZpQ and with doctype https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpYGRm

Comment: textbox is always wider around 22px and taller around 4px than it is supposed to be

Comment: All modern web pages are required to have a doctype. Without one, you are in "quirks mode" and it's like 1999 all over again. Keep the doctype and "fix" the rest of your CSS to comply with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the code below to your lower input to include padding and border in the element's total width and height. This should solve it.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome!